# Is it possible to have only large titles in the navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I want my application to have large titles, however, when the user scrolls, I don't want the regular/normal navigation bar to appear. I just want the large bar to scroll up along with the tableview. Is this possible without making custom views in the navigation bar? I have done it successfully with custom views, but it isn't as fluid and putting a UISearchController inside is a pain.

```
func createNavController(vc: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage, tag: Int) -> UINavigationController {
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = .headerColor
    navController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: title, image: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), tag: tag)
    navController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = title
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.headerColor, .font: UIFont.customHeaderFont(size: 25)]
    navController.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.headerColor, .font: UIFont.customHeaderFont(size: 40)]
//        let titleLabel = UILabel()
//        titleLabel.text = title
//        titleLabel.textColor = .headerColor
//        titleLabel.font = UIFont.customHeaderFont(size: navController.navigationBar.frame.height - 5)
//        navController.navigationBar.addSubview(titleLabel)
//        titleLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: navController.navigationBar.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
//        titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    return navController
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my extension iOS 13 Swift 5 tested

```
extension UIViewController {
func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor

        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationItem.title = title

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationItem.title = title
    }
}}
```

How to use:

```
configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .yourColor, backgoundColor: .yourColor, tintColor: .yourColor, title: "yuorTitle", preferredLargeTitle: true)
```

Set ViewController-based status bar...... to NO in info.plist if you want light Content

If you don't want largeTitles set it to false

for tranlsucent change navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground() in:

```
navBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

in the call set background color to .clear

**UPDATE**: If you want to start with navigation controller and large Titles at first controller, don't forget to set launch controller in Scene Delegate like this:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
let vC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourFirstViewController())
window?.rootViewController = vC
```

hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probe create your custom navigation controller and called in your view controllers; is more easy, customize the native navigation controller is hard, but you can do it scouring subviews in the natives elements.

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution: (just set small title font to zero, easy way)

```
self.title = "Title text"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0)]
```